# how to Call database view in silverlight ria service project?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, binding

Can we call database view useing Silverlight ria service and bind data to ui .If some  , any samples.. in the web?

Is there any limitation.
?
Thanky

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. [This](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/) post should be helpful. Once you have successfully created an entity, it should bind just like every other entity to UI components.